# Showing interstitial ad on separate android:process

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, interstitial

I have an activity I'd like to run under a separate process. I have defined this in my manifest under android:process but as soon as I do, I'm unable to display any interstitial ads. If I take it off the process, it works perfectly. Is there a way to do this or am I limited to the main process?

Here is my manifest definition:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.Activity"
        android:process=":custom"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="Activity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Update 1: I've had some luck messing with TaskAffinity and ParentActivityName (setting them both to self references), but even when I do get the ad to show, my listener is lost as the ad is shown on the main thread.

Update 2: I reached out to AdMob support and was informed that this was a *known* issue and there is no solution at this time. I'll update this if/when I hear back.

Comment: Why do you need a separate process?

Comment: I'm working on a launcher that has some baked in "applications". I need to ensure that if these crash or are closed that they do not affect the launcher.